# helping out beginner to locate main source code for web he didnt make

Tags: php, web

im new here..

right now im trying to make a change to to this specific website that im not the one making it, its kinda hard to understand someone else source code for a beginner like me..
what im trying to ask here is where do you usually find the main source code in this kind of web setup?

First Directory
[image: Directory image]

Second Directory
[image: second directory image]

Comment: The "kind of setup" you have taken screenshots of, is a typical cPanel/WHM hosted layout. `public_html` usually contains the website source, but may be nested further or in another folder off of the account root, depending on how the server was configured and user choices when adding a new (sub)domain.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can find the main source code in public_html directory.

Answer (score 0):

if your using xampp than you want to create website folder in htdocs